# iPhone - Parsing an NSMutableArray to remove objects

Tags: iphone, crash, nsuserdefaults, collision

I have an object that act on UserDefaults.
It adds things into an Array into userdefaults, then removes it when some events occurs.
That object can have more than one instance.

Those calls coming from different objects instance seems to collide and generate a crash :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFArray: 0x66061e0> was mutated while being enumerated.<CFArray 0x66061e0 [0xe38400]>{type = mutable-small, count = 3, values = (
```

I remove my items like this :

```
// ==========================================================================================================
- (void) deleteSavedItem:(NSString*)keycodeToDelete
// ==========================================================================================================
{   
    NSMutableArray* savedItems = [[self loadAllSavedItems] mutableCopy];

    for (NSDictionary* dict in savedItems) {
        NSString* keycode = [dict objectForKey:@"keycode"];
        if ([keycode isEqualToString:keycodeToDelete])
            [savedItems removeObject:dict];
    }

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:savedItems forKey:@"savedItems"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [savedItems release];
}

// ==========================================================================================================
- (NSArray*) loadAllSavedItems 
// ==========================================================================================================
{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray* savedItems = [defaults arrayForKey:@"savedItems"];
    if (savedItems == nil) savedItems = [NSArray array];
    return savedItems;
}
```

How may I add/remove things from that array without collision ?
I'm not sure the reason is the many objects that use default that causes this crash. I suspect too that this is the way I parse the array.

I need to keep my objects instances, and keep them running process parralel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must never alter an array while fast enumerating it. It will raise an exception as it did for you. You can get the items that satisfy your condition using

```
NSArray * matchingItems = [savedItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" keycode MATCHES[cd] %@ ", keycodeToDelete]];
```

and then remove them using,

```
[savedItems removeObjectsInArray:matchingItems];
```

Modified `deleteSavedItem:` would be.

```
- (void)deleteSavedItem:(NSString *)keycodeToDelete {
    NSMutableArray * savedItems    = [[self loadAllSavedItems] mutableCopy];
    NSArray        * matchingItems = [savedItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" keycode MATCHES[cd] %@ ", keycodeToDelete]];

    [savedItems removeObjectsInArray:matchingItems];

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:savedItems forKey:@"savedItems"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [savedItems release];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ? My array contains NSDictionary object. The keycode is the value on an item which key is "keycode".

Comment: @Oliver I am sure. I am providing the key path so it should work. You can do that with dictionaries. As such you should be able to test it.

Comment: I'll try. May I ask you what should be the way to do this if the array was an array of custom class insatnces that has a .keycode attribute ?

Comment: If it is a property, the same thing should apply.

Comment: Thank you, you're a master :-)  I'm reading the huge doc about predicates, and I have just one question before spending hours onto that doc. In which contexts may predicates be usefull ? Here we can see an example on an array, but are there other situations where predicates could be usefully used ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try synchonizing the add/remove from the NSUSerDefaults array

Answer (score 0):

```
        // ==========================================================================================================
    - (void) deleteSavedItem:(NSString*)keycodeToDelete
        // ==========================================================================================================
    {   
        NSMutableArray* savedItems = [self loadAllSavedItems];

        for (NSDictionary* dict in savedItems) {
            NSString* keycode = [dict objectForKey:@"keycode"];
            if ([keycode isEqualToString:keycodeToDelete])
                [savedItems removeObject:dict];
        }

        NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setValue:savedItems forKey:@"savedItems"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        [savedItems release];
    }

        // ==========================================================================================================
    - (NSMutableArray*) loadAllSavedItems 
        // ==========================================================================================================
    {
        NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableArray* savedItems = [defaults arrayForKey:@"savedItems"];
        if (savedItems == nil) savedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        return savedItems;
    }
```

Comment: while enumurate u have modify the NSArray.so please use NSMutableArray  which is mutable and will help u.